# MS SQL Sort Alphanumeric values (1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 4a, 8a, 4b, 8b)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

In SQL database (2005/2008), I have a field named Ordernumber having the following values: 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 4a, 8a, 4b, 8b I want a way to sort them to be 1, 2, 3, 4a, 4b, 5, 6, 7, 8a, 8b, 9, 10. How to do?

I used the following:

```
SELECT Ordernumber
FROM alphanumericorder
ORDER BY
  CASE
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(Ordernumber) = 1 THEN CAST(Ordernumber AS INT)
    ELSE CAST(SUBSTRING(Ordernumber, 1, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Ordernumber) - 1) AS VARCHAR(100)) 
      + RIGHT('0000000000' + CAST(SUBSTRING(Ordernumber, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Ordernumber), LEN(Ordernumber)) AS VARCHAR(100)), 10)
  END
```

but I got the following error: "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '000000004a' to data type int"

Then I used:

```
  SELECT Ordernumber
FROM alphanumericorder
ORDER BY
  CASE
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(LEFT(Ordernumber,1)) = 1 THEN CAST(Ordernumber AS INT)
    ELSE CAST(LEFT(Ordernumber,LEN(Ordernumber)-1) AS VARCHAR(100)) 
      + RIGHT('0000000000' + CAST(RIGHT(Ordernumber,1) AS VARCHAR(100)), 1)
  END;
```

and I got: "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '4a' to data type int"

Please advise.

Comment: Both 2005 and 2008 are *completed unsupported* for about 3/8 years; you really need to get your upgrade plan implementes. Which are you really using too? Both lack a lot of basic functionality taken for granted in more "modern" versions.

Comment: Hello @ThomA, actually this is a production database and has a lot of dependencies that is based on old version of SQL, we planned last year to convert it but it was a nightmare as a lots of SPs had errors, so we are asking for SQL pro people to provide a workaround or any custom solution.

Comment: The _best_ thing to do here would be to store the major and minor versions in separate columns, i.e. store `4a` and `4` and `a`.

Comment: The issue is that one part of your CASE is an INT, so the ELSE part must also be converted to INT. This won't work due to the fact that you have a stringy value

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Is there a way to do this while querying? I mean to create a stored procedure that will split the order number into many field then sort them? I'm not really that much experienced on SQL but what I know is that it is too late for us to create multiple columns as 1000+ of records already entered by the users.

Comment: @siggemannen, yep that's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```sql
select *
from (
    VALUES  (N'1')
    ,   (N'2')
    ,   (N'3')
    ,   (N'5')
    ,   (N'6')
    ,   (N'7')
    ,   (N'9')
    ,   (N'10')
    ,   (N'4a')
    ,   (N'8a')
    ,   (N'4b')
    ,   (N'8b')
) t ([Ordernumber])
order by CASE
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(Ordernumber) = 1 THEN CAST(Ordernumber AS INT)
    ELSE CAST(SUBSTRING(Ordernumber, 1, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', Ordernumber)-1) AS INT)
  END, OrderNumber
```

This converts the number part of the ordernumber by stripping everything from first non-numbered digit

Comment: Hi, your solution did most of the trick, however I got 8b before 8a in the results while I got 4a then 4b as expected, odd.

Comment: Good catch, i changed the code a bit, and added a tiebreaker as OrderNumber, that should solve the issue i think

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick :) I marked your response as answer.

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` does weird stuff and should be avoided, `TRY_CAST AS int` is much better.